# How to build a simple HTML Form that sends email on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, sendmail, forms

I'm new to Firebase. I just want to build a **simple HTML form** on **Firebase** that sends email to me as well as to the user who fills up the form upon submit button click. I do not need any user authentication or database. After that I want this HTML form to be able to **embed on my Blogger website**, probably using `iFrame`. So how can I go about doing this?

Based on my understanding, for a HTML form to send email requires **server-side coding** like ASP.NET and PHP, may I know which language should I use on Firebase? Does Firebase provide such SDK that I can simply write in JavaScript and create a **.js** file for my form handler?

I already know how to deploy HTML files to my Firebase project using **Node.js** and get the URL of every file that I deployed, e.g. images, css files etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Post what you have done

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. I just need a direction. I can't find any of this on Firebase documentation. I want to know how to send email on Firebase server using SMTP and what server-side scripting I should use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**With Third Parties** (by now)...

After many hours researching about this, the solution seems not to be inside Google at the moment, but using a third party: SendGrid.

Tyson Bailey created a small example and explains this methodology in [**this blog post**](http://blog.onaclovtech.com/2014/07/emailster.html).